# Q linear convergence of larger sequence implies Q linear convergence of smallersequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, rate-of-convergence

A postitive sequence $\{x_k\}$ converges Q-linearly to $0$ if there is some $\mu\in(0,1)$ and $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ x_{k+1}\le \mu x_k \text{ for }k\ge K.$$

If $\{x_k\}$ converges linearly to $0$ and $0< y_k\le x_k$ for all $k$, does it mean that $y_k$ converges Q-linearly to $0?$

Comment: What is your definition of just "linear" convergence? Because the definition I know for that is effectively what you are calling "Q-linear".

Comment: Assuming that you mean $x_k$ converges Q-linearly to $0$, consider $x_k = \left(\frac 23\right)^k$ and $$y_k = \begin{cases}x_k&k \text{ odd}\\\frac {x_k}2&k\text{ even}\end{cases}$$.

Comment: The definition I looked at this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence

Comment: @PaulSinclair Could you please elaborate more about what do we get from the constructions of x_k and y_k?

Comment: So what definition of just "linear" convergence are you using? Since you describe $x_k$ as just coverging "linearly" instead of "Q-linearly", I am trying to figure out the difference. Or was it a typo as I supposed in my second comment. As for the example I gave: Obviously $x_k$ is Q-linear with $\mu = \frac 23$ and $0 < y_k \le x_k$. Try figuring out the convergence of $y_k$. Does it meet your definition of Q-linear convergence?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, x_k meets my definition of Q-linear convergence (the definition I stated in the question). Sorry if it causes any inconvenience to you.

Comment: The question was about $y_k$, not $x_k$. That $x_k$ meets your definition is obvious.

Comment: Yes, I know but I do not have any ideas to prove. I still think that if the answer for my question is yes, i.e. y_k is also linearly convergent to 0.

Comment: Examine the ratios of $y_{k+1}$ to $y_k$ when $k$ is even, and when $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no since we can choose $x^k=\mu^k$ for all $k\ge 1$ and $y^{2k-1}=y^{2k}=\mu^{2k}$ for all $k\ge 1$. Then for $\mu<1$, it is clear that $x^k$ converges $Q$-linearly to $0$, $y^k\le x^k$ for all $k$ but $y^k$ does not converges $Q$-linearly to $0.$